# Ajax complete not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, visual-studio

I have this common JavaScript function that handles all Ajax requests of my ASP.NET web forms application:

```
var xsrf_token, IsAjaxAsync = true;
function callAjax(Handler, ajaxData, Cache, BeforeSend, Complete, Reset) {
    var URL = "http://" + window.location.host + "/Handlers/" + Handler + ".ashx";
    $.retryAjax({
        url: URL,
        type: "POST",
        timeout: 5000,
        retryLimit: 3,
        data: JSON.stringify({
            XSRFToken: xsrf_token,
            Data: ajaxData
        }),
        dataType: "json",
        cache: Cache,
        async: IsAjaxAsync,
        beforeSend: BeforeSend,
        success: function (data) {
            var resp = parseInt(data);
            if (resp != -10) {
                Complete(data);
            } else {
                $.prompt("Please login to perform this operation.", {
                    title: "Logged Out",
                    close: function () {
                        window.location.href = "http://" + window.location.host + "/Login";
                    }
                });
            }
        },
        complete: function () {
            UpdateHistory();
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textstatus, error) {
            if (textstatus == 0) showConnectionError();
            if (Reset != null) Reset();
        }
    });
}
```

This function is actually using this plugin to call ajax: https://github.com/mberkom/jQuery.retryAjax

But it seems this function is unable to call `complete` callback which I want to call in every situation. Whether some error occurs, or request is successful or even if `success` callback return false or something else.

I tried to add breakpoint at line 31 but it's not reaching there. Please tell me how can I call this `UpdateHistory()` in each situation? I don't want it to be called in each function that uses this `callAjax()` function.

One more thing I want to ask is that if `success` stuck in some infinite loop or some long term process, then still `complete` will be called? And what are various situations in which `complete` is skipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in line 21 in the [retryAjax source](https://github.com/mberkom/jQuery.retryAjax/blob/master/dist/jquery.retryAjax.js), your complete callback is overridden, as this is a very simple plugin, I suggest that you change the plugin code to fit your own needs, by applying the following change :

```
ajaxParams.complete = function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    if ($.inArray(textStatus, ['timeout', 'abort', 'error']) > -1) {
        this.tryCount++;
        if (this.tryCount <= this.retryLimit) {

            // fire error handling on the last try
            if (this.tryCount === this.retryLimit) {
                this.error = errorCallback;
                delete this.suppressErrors;
            }

            //try again
            $.ajax(this);
            return true;
        }

        //window.alert('There was a server error.  Please refresh the page.  If the issue persists, give us a call. Thanks!');
        ajaxParams.myCompleteCallback(jqXHR, textStatus);
    }
    ajaxParams.myCompleteCallback(jqXHR, textStatus);
};
```

and then, instead of passing a complete callback called complete, just pass a complete callback called myCompleteCallback